# How to customize the list of figure page from `.cls` file?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have been preparing a `.cls` file modifying the `article.cls`. I need to customize the list of figure page of my document.

The list of figure part of my `.cls` file is as follows:

```
    \newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        \begin{flushright}
            {\bf\pagename}
        \end{flushright}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{-4.9em}{4.9em}}
```

When I use the

```
\listoffigures
```

code to print the list of figure page, it produces it as follows:

```
1.1        Caption of Figure 1.1  .................. 12
1.2        Caption of Figure 1.2  .................. 17
2.1        Caption of Figure 2.1  .................. 25
2.2        Caption of Figure 2.2  .................. 26
```

But, the required list of figures page must be as follows:

```
Figure 1.1 Caption of Figure 1.1  .................. 12
Figure 1.2 Caption of Figure 1.2  .................. 17
Figure 2.1 Caption of Figure 2.1  .................. 25
Figure 2.2 Caption of Figure 2.2  .................. 26
```

For this, how can I modify the `.cls` file?

Comment: you have tagged your question with `tocloft` and then rejected an answer that uses it!

Comment: I do not think, that `listoffigures` is really the problem here, but rather the way how `\caption` writes the entry to the `.lof` file. One approach might be the usage of `caption` package.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a redefinition of `\listoffigures` but uses the facilities provided by the very sophisticated `caption` package by defining a `figurenew` listformat, with prefix `Figure` (as contained `\figurename`) and a slight redefinition of `\l@figure` which must be changed to `\newcommand{\l@figure}` in the class file, if no `\LoadClass{article}` is used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{7em}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figurenew}{\textbf{\figurename}~#1 #2}%
\captionsetup{listformat=figurenew}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\section{first}


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{somefig}%
\caption{Some caption number one}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{somefig}%
\caption{Some caption number one}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{section}{99}

\section{Hundred}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{somefig}%
\caption{Some caption number three}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{report}
\def\pagename{Page}
\makeatletter
   \renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        \begin{flushright}
            {\bf\pagename}
        \end{flushright}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{-4.9em}{4.9em}}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{Figure \csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{figure}
foo\caption{bar}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]